# Confusion regarding Mongo db Schema. How to make it better?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose with node.js for this.

My current Schema is this:

```
var linkSchema = new Schema({

    text: String,
    tags: array,
    body: String,
    user: String
})
```

My use-case is this:  There are a list of users and each user has a list of links associated with it. Users and links are different Schemas of course. Thus, how does one get that sort of one to one relationship done using mongo-db.

Should I make a User Schema and embed linkSchema in it? Or the other way around?

Another doubt regarding that. Tags would always be an array of strings which I can use to browse through links later. Should it be an array data type or is there a better way to represent it?

Answer (score 1):

If it's 1:1 then nest one document inside the other. Which way around depends on the queries, but you could easily do both if you need to.

For tags, you can index an array field and use that for searching/filtering documents and from the information you've given that sounds reasonable IMHO.

If you had a fixed set of tags it would make sense to represent those as a nested object with named fields perhaps, depending on queries. Don't forget you not only can create nested documents in Mongo but you can also search on sub-fields and even use entire nested documents as searchable/indexable fields. For instance, you could have a username like this;

```
email: "joe@somewhere.com"
```

as a string, and you could also do;

```
 email: {
     user: "joe",
     domain: "somewhere.com"
 }
```

you could index email in both cases and use either for matching. In the latter case though you could also search on domain or user only without resorting to RegEx style queries. You could also store both variants, so there's lots of flexibile options in Mongo.

Going back to tags, I think your array of strings is a fine model given what you've described, but if you were doing more complex bulk aggregation, it wouldn't be crazy to store a document for every tag with the same document contents, since that's essentially what you'd have to do for every query during aggregation.